# The "Info" bar on top disappeared and the mouse pointer is misaligned

Tags: customization

I have a problem with Blenders UI. The "Info" bar on top disappeared and the mouse pointer is misaligned. I reinstalled Blender 2 times, deleted every leftover files  but it still does the same thing. This is in v2.78c. The weird thing is that on the bottom everything works fine. Here are some images:[image]

[image]

Comment: below image looks fine with info bar and the cursor

Comment: Yes I can drag it down but everytime I open Blender I have to drag it down, and the pointer is still misaligned. You're supposed to drag the info bar where the the window (white bar) ends. Also as I said before the bottom bars work fine. It's making me crazy!

Comment: I'm guessing this is the same issue as in [this question](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/82077/2217).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Consider this solved. It is a driver problem (Intel HD 530 version 15.45.19.4678 doesn't work properly)

Comment: I'm had the same issue and same driver issue, rollback it is.

Comment: I had the same issue with Intel HD 530 version 21.20.16.4664 Rolling back also . . .