# Top Menu set in preferences

Tags: customization

[image]Windows has just done an update and now when I open Blender 2.78c the top menu line has collapsed. Is there a way of setting it to be there, in preferences or startup?

Also the pointer now has to be a few mm below anything I want to select being it a menu item or anything else it seems to be offset.

Comment: ok i worked out that i need to save the start up file Ctrl + U

Comment: however the pointer does need to be a feww mm belowanything i select and not exactly on top anyone experienced this?

Comment: Try resetting the UI with *File* > *Load Factory Settings*

Comment: difficult to post a screen shot when the pointer does not show up. If you for instance hover over an item in one of the menus the item above is highlighted so in main view it is difficult to set the 3d curser as when clicked it moves toa few mm away from where the pointer is. i am using a logitech M185 mouse but my laptop touchpad acts the same also i plugged in a USB mouse same thing.

Comment: Factory settings makes no difference.

Comment: Maybe related - https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned

Comment: how do i mark this question as resolved?

Comment: rolling back the driver and now works ok no offset