# Blender3d not displaying correctly

Tags: interface, edit-mode

[image: Blender's rendered useless as I can't access the toolbar and options menu]

Blender's rendered useless as I can't access the toolbar and options menu.
The cursor also selects things that are above it, for the example, on the side if I want to select the Camera, I'd have to click on the lamp.

I've tried running it in compatibility mode and playing with the window settings to a degree.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned

Comment: Have you recently updated your video drivers? I had this exact problem when I upgraded to the newest Intel drivers. I had to downgrade again to the previous version of the drivers (actually the version released by my laptop manufacturer) before Blender worked again properly. EDIT - I see possible duplicate is the saying the same thing, I suspect the OP's problem is indeed this.