# Weird panel appears after any render

Tags: rendering, interface

Every render event(i.e. <kbd>F12</kbd> or <kbd>⌃ Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F12</kbd>) results in appearance of the panel marked on the image below.

Stretching it using mouse helps remove it. In other words, it disappears if stretched.
Also, it's worth to mention that clicking on the arrow, located on the panel on the middle-top area of the image, does nothing.

The image:
[image]

It nearly prevents clicking on the tabs and also hides them:
[image]

```
Blender: 2.91.2, 5be9ef417703, master, 2021-01-19 16:15, as found on the splash screen.
OS: Win10x64
```

I'd appreciate for the suggestion.

Comment: Did you try to update / revert gpu drivers? This looks surprisingly similar to old bugs of [this kind](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/82130/the-info-bar-on-top-disappeared-and-the-mouse-pointer-is-misaligned) and it looks like this is a bug since Blender's UI elements shouldn't be overlayed with any "menus" of that kind

Comment: It only appears when the `F12` key is being hit, it seems. The question you mentioned looks quite different. There's no oversized panel, but an additional, empty one. I'm sorry, but why would a GPU driver be related to the UI element appearance?